# Create heap dump in Azure service

Tags: java, azure, error-handling, azure-web-app-service, out-of-memory

web service hosted at azure . web service crashed due to OutOfMemoryException error . so need to analyse the root cause . For this I have to configured heap dump in azure.

Can someone help me for how to configured heap dump in azure portal.

Comment: If you can set JVM parameters use `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking question! There are two  ways to get the JVM heap dump file as below.

1. Command "jmap -dump:format=b,file=.hprof "
2. Add the JVM arguments for java startup. Option "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" enables heap dumps when an OutOfMemoryError occurs. And option "-XX:HeapDumpPath=" specify the dump location, that default location for the dump file is the current working directory.

Check: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/#application-configuration-examples

Also, You may use GUI tool of Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT, https://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Comment: I have to set up heap dump in Azure portal .